# Suppose $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p>3$, where $p$ is prime. Show that $p$ is of form $x^2+3y^2$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Suppose $-3$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p>3$, where $p$ is prime. Show that $p$ is of form $x^2+3y^2$.

I have shown that the standard norm on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ and the norm on $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ given by $N(a+b\zeta_3)=a^2-ab+b^2$ have the same image. (Here, $\zeta_3$ is a primitive cubic root of unity, so $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ is the Eisenstein integers.) I believe I am supposed to use this fact to prove my claim. In other words, given by $p\mid n^2+3$ for some $n$, I need to show that there is some polynomial in $\zeta_3$ with integer coefficients such that taking norm will yield $p$.

Any and all help would be appreciated. I know the usual argument in this kind of situation is to appeal to unique factorization and proceed without this business of showing that the norm image coincides with the norm image of the Eisenstein integers, but unfortunately $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a UFD.

Comment: Using the Legendre symbol (a/p) and its properties would make this a simple proof by induction. Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: @bloomers I don't see why not, although it is not clear how one would do this either.

Comment: But $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}2]=\mathbb Z[\zeta_3]$ is a UFD!

Comment: @Mathmo123 Ah, I see how to do this now. You indeed provide the key ingredient. One may simply do the standard argument thinking of the divisibility relation occurring inside $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ and then appeal to unique factorization, only passing to the smaller ring at the end using the fact that the norms have identical image. Thank you very much.